# Show this modal popup once per session

Tags: sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

I have implemented a modal popup in sharepoint 2016 from a tutorial on another site with this code:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
    });  

    function showModalPopUp() {  
        //Set options for Modal PopUp  
        var options = {  
            url: 'https://testurl.nl', //Set the url of the page  
            title: 'Testpopup', //Set the title for the pop up  
            allowMaximize: false,  
            showClose: true,  
            width: 600,  
            height: 400  
        };  
        //Invoke the modal dialog by passing in the options array variable  
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);  
        return false;  
    }  
</script>
```

Now i need this popup to open once per user per day, or if that can't be done once per session. How do i do this using the code above?

Comment: I think these articles would help you **[Show SharePoint Modal Popup Once Per Session](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)** and **[JQuery Modal Popup once Per Session in SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/load-fancybox-popup-in-first-load-of-sharepoint-site/)**

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is with a cookie which only lasts 24 hours.

What you'd do is check if there was a cookie and show the dialog if there isn't

```
if($.cookie('MyCookie') != 'DialogShown'){
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
  setCookie();
}
```

Note: Above code write under document.ready method.

Here's the code to set cookies. Declare function in your file.

```
function setCookie(){
    $.cookie('MyCookie', 'DialogShown',
      {
         expires: date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // now add 24 hours
      });
}
```

Thanks.